# Remove previous alertDialog if another one is called Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a series of alertDialog into my app which collect information from the user
what I want is once an alertDialog is called and into his OnPressed function I use:

```
showDialog(
                    context: context, builder: (context) => AnotherAlert());
```

I want to close the previous alertDialog otherwise the situation is to have a number of alertdialog like the picture...
[image]

as you can see there are 2 alertdialog I want to close the previuos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling the second dialog, just do a

`Navigator.pop(context);`

Then, show the second dialog as next code line. Use both lines in the same method called by onPressed of the first dialog.

Something like this:

```
onPressed:(){
   Navigator.pop(context);
   showSecondDialog();
}
```